# SQL - SELECT LEFT JOIN removes a row instead of having a NULL value in column

Tags: sql, select, null, db2, left-join

I have this SQL query and it returns following table:

```
    select tk1.ticketid,tk1.ownergroup,tk1.CHANGEDATE as dateentered 
    from tkstatus as tk1
    where TK1.TICKETID='SR4402' and ownergroup is not null
    ORDER BY  dateentered

TICKETID    OWNERGROUP                 DATEENTERED
SR4402      CONTROLDESK-ESB        2017-05-17 14:01:32
SR4402      IT-ZAŠTITA             2017-05-24 13:11:34
SR4402      IT-PODRŠKA             2017-05-24 13:30:57
SR4402      IT-ZAŠTITA             2017-05-24 13:46:17
SR4402      IT-PODRŠKA             2017-05-24 13:52:52
SR4402      IT-ZAŠTITA             2017-05-24 14:12:32
```

TKSTATUS table has integer primary column `TKSTATUSID` which is unique for every row and every next row has larger next value.

Now for every row I want to find when that record EXITED that group which means that is time of the following group.
So basically for this table I should have again 6 rows but the last row should have that column `DATEEXITED NULL` since it is still in that group.
So I wrote this query:

```
select tk1.ticketid,tk1.status,tk1.ownergroup,
tk1.CHANGEDATE as dateentered,tk2.changedate as dateexited  
from tkstatus as    tk1
left outer join tkstatus as tk2 on tk2.ticketid=tk1.ticketid
where 
tk2.tkstatusid in (
    SELECT MIN(tk3.TKSTATUSID) 
    FROM TKSTATUS as tk3
    WHERE tk3.TICKETID=tk2.ticketid AND tk3.ownergroup is not null 
    and tk3.ownergroup!=tk1.ownergroup AND tk3.CHANGEDATE>tk1.changedate
)    
AND TK1.TICKETID='SR4402' 
ORDER BY  dateentered
```

And this returns 5 rows instead of 6!!!
I want 6th row to have column `DATEEXITED  null`

```
TICKETID      OWNERGROUP          DATEENTERED         DATEEXITED
SR4402     CONTROLDESK-ESB    2017-05-17 14:01:32   2017-05-24 13:11:34
SR4402       IT-ZAŠTITA       2017-05-24 13:11:34   2017-05-24 13:30:57
SR4402       IT-PODRŠKA       2017-05-24 13:30:57   2017-05-24 13:46:17
SR4402       IT-ZAŠTITA       2017-05-24 13:46:17   2017-05-24 13:52:52
SR4402       IT-PODRŠKA       2017-05-24 13:52:52   2017-05-24 14:12:32
```

I want somehow to have and last row like this

```
SR4402      IT-ZAŠTITA             2017-05-24 14:12:32   NULL
```

Important notes:

1. `TKSTATUSID` is the primary unique column for `TKSTATUS` table
2. I tried before to have `TKSTATUSID` within the `JOIN` after `ON` but then SQLSTATE error 42972 was returned because I cannot have `IN` and `MIN` after the JOIN.

So this does not work (error is returned).

```
 left outer join tkstatus as tk2 on 
      tk2.ticketid=tk1.ticketid
 and  tk2.tkstatusid in (
      SELECT  MIN(tk3.TKSTATUSID)
      FROM    TKSTATUS as tk3
      WHERE   tk3.TICKETID=tk2.ticketid
          AND tk3.ownergroup is not null 
          and tk3.ownergroup!=tk1.ownergroup
          and tk3.CHANGEDATE>tk1.changedate)
```

Comment: You need to move the condition for `tk2.tkstatusid` out of the where and into the JOIN condition

Comment: Can you please write what you exactly meant?

Comment: Please check my updated question. I already tried to put TKSTATUSID in JOIN but then I have issue because for the same query sqlstate 42972 is returned

Comment: @Dejan Lounis's answer demonstrates using LEAD with a partition. Apparently it was added to DB2 in version 9.7. So if possible, it's highly recommended that you make use of it. Apart from being much easier to read, it should perform much better than my answer (which is the fallback for databases that don't support these features).

Comment: @Dejan Why were you unable to use the answer you accepted on your previous and very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226967/224704)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the where statement after the join. I don't know if you have to use a join, but if you want to produce your result using lead, you can simply use:

```
select ticketid,ownergroup,CHANGEDATE as dateentered, 
lead(CHANGEDATE) over (partition by TICKETID order by CHANGEDATE) as dateexited
from tkstatus as tk1
where TK1.TICKETID='SR4402' and ownergroup is not null
ORDER BY dateentered
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding exactly how OUTER JOIN works.
The JOIN condition will include missing rows in the OUTER table.

```
left outer join tkstatus as tk2 on tk2.ticketid=tk1.ticketid
```

So if you were missing any `tk2` rows for given `tk1` rows, the `tk1` would still be included, but all `tk2` values for that row would be `NULL`.

You've indicated this is not the case, which suggests using OUTER JOIN is unnecessary.

Note that the WHERE clause is effectively a filter applied ***after*** the join. If you change you SELECT columns as follows and comment out the WHERE clause, you should observe the problem.

```
SELECT  tk1.ticketid, tk1.status, tk1.ownergroup,
        tk1.CHANGEDATE as dateentered,
        tk2.changedate as dateexited,
        tk2.tkstatusid,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(tk3.TKSTATUSID) 
        FROM    TKSTATUS as tk3
        WHERE   tk3.TICKETID=tk2.ticketid
            AND tk3.ownergroup is not null 
            and tk3.ownergroup!=tk1.ownergroup
            AND tk3.CHANGEDATE>tk1.changedate
        ) as MinTk3StatusId
 /* Rest of your query. .... Spelt out because apparently it wasn't obvious enough! */
```

Your WHERE clause was requiring that `tk2.tkstatusid` be equal to the value returned by the sub-query. (Note that use of `IN` is pointless because the sub-query only ever returns a single aggregated value.)

You'll no doubt discover that for the row that was being filtered out by the WHERE clause, the last 2 columns are not the same.

Actually, I think I've figured out what you're trying to do. It looks like a self join to determine the ChangeDate of the next item in the selection. Your query can be significantly simplified by rather using a sub-query column as follows.

```
select  tk1.ticketid, tk1.status, tk1.ownergroup,
        tk1.CHANGEDATE as dateentered,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(tk2.CHANGEDATE) 
        FROM    TKSTATUS as tk2
        WHERE   tk2.TICKETID=tk1.ticketid 
            /*Hopefully I've got this logic correct*/
            AND tk2.ownergroup != tk1.OwnerGroup
            and tk2.CHANGEDATE > tk1.changedate
        ) AS DateExited
from    TkStatus tk1
where   tk1.TICKETID = 'SR4402'
```

However, it would be more efficient to use "windowing or ranking" features. I don't know if DB2 supports this or what syntax it would use. But feel free to investigate further if my proposed solution isn't fast enough.

Comment: Hi, this does not work I still have 5 rows in result. TKSTATUSID is the primary unique key for this table which I am talking about and TKSTATUSID is always populated

Comment: can you please check again since this is not working what you have suggested? Thank you

Comment: @Dejan Difficult for me to check when I don't have your data. ;) Since you've indicated that `tk2.tkstatusid` is always populated, the problem is slightly different. But you're still misunderstanding OUTER JOINS. I'll update my answer.

Comment: tkstatusid is always populated since it is unique column in tkstatus I will update my question

Comment: Hi Craig, in your first SQL query where is the TK2 defined??? I cannot see that you defined what  is TK2 can you please check? Thank you

Comment: Second query does not work.  I wrote that it returns 42972 error. Can you please write FIRST query completely correct to work since it seems it is not properly written?

Comment: Are you missing a JOIN before the brace? Thanks

Comment: @Dejan First query is just the change to the SELECT clause. `tk2` is in the FROM clause as per your query. The second query I've replaced because I think I've figured out what you're trying to do. It doesn't require a JOIN at all, but it is a correlated sub-query; which can be inefficient on large tables.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts I will examine it but I still do not see where did you state which table is TK2? I see that you are only using it in selection

Comment: @Dejan If you're still referring to my first query: You stated tk2 ***in your own*** FROM clause: `from tkstatus as tk1 left outer join tkstatus as tk2 on tk2.ticketid=tk1.ticketid`